# "echo" prints the options in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, raspberry-pi, echo

I'm running Rasbian 3.12.26+ on a Pi model B.

Here is what my cron entry looks like:

```
* * * * * sleep 11; { echo -en "\e[1;4;33m"; date; echo -en "\e[0m"; curl -k "http://sampleurl.com/update.php"; } >> /var/log/cron/calls.log
```

Here is what my log looks like:

```
-en \e[1;4;33m
Thu Sep  4 14:29:13 UTC 2014
-en \e[0m
This is output from curl!
```

However, when I just paste the command into bash, it works as intended:

```
{ echo -en "\e[1;4;33m"; date; echo -en "\e[0m"; curl -k "http://sampleurl.com/update.php"; } >> /var/log/cron/calls.log
```

And the output is

```
Thu Sep  4 14:27:51 UTC 2014
This is output from curl!
```

With the first line underlined, bold and yellow as intended.

For some reason, when run by a crontab, the echo prints the "-en" instead of taking it as an argument. As a result, the color escape sequences do not get escaped.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably that cron uses /bin/sh.  See for yourself by comparing the output of the following:

```
/bin/sh -c '{ echo -en "\e[1;4;33m"; date; echo -en "\e[0m"; curl -k "http://sampleurl.com/update.php" ; } > /tmp/1'
```

The above produces the output you are getting

```
/bin/bash -c '{ echo -en "\e[1;4;33m"; date; echo -en "\e[0m"; curl -k "http://sampleurl.com/update.php" ; } > /tmp/1'
```

Whereas the same command under bash produces the output you want

Comment: How can I change which shell crontab executes?

Comment: add SHELL=/bin/bash on top of your cron

Comment: Another way to get your escape sequences to produce color is to change `echo` (which the shell treats as a built-in command) to `/bin/echo` (which is a separate program). (If that doesn't work, try `/usr/bin/echo`.)